# Salesforce lightning Standard Navigation openPrimaryTab() not working

Tags: lightning, community, salesforce1-app, integration, lightning-console

I am using the openPrimaryTab() method to open a custom page as tab.

```
<script src="/support/console/43.0/integration.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPrimaryTab() {
        //Open a new primary tab with the appropriate case in it
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, 'http://www.salesforce.com', false, 'salesforce', openSuccess, 'salesforceTab');
    }

    var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
        //Report whether opening the new tab was successful
        if (result.success == true) {
            alert('Primary tab successfully opened');
        } else {
            alert('Primary tab cannot be opened');
        }
    };
</script>
```

Its working in Console Navigation in Salesforce lightning view.
But its not working in Standard Navigation in Salesforce lightning view.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning already offers `lightning:workspaceAPI`, which provides access to console controls.

Here you can see an example:

```
({
   openTab : function(component, event, helper) {
       var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
       workspaceAPI.openTab({
           url: '#/sObject/001R0000003HgssIAC/view',
           focus: true
       });
   },
})
```

See the reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_workspaceAPI.htm).

Comment: Thanks for update. Without any components its possible to open new tab in Salesforce lightning standard navigation.